# Get the value of dynamically added select box and text box in jquery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am very new to jQuery,here I need to add/remove a set of textbox and select box in a row by clicking a button.
While Adding i have to populate the same select box with options.
i have achieved add and remove by the following code.

```
============Add=================

var i = 1; 
$("‪#‎add‬").click(function() {
i++;
$(".normal-tble tbody tr:first").clone().find("select,input").each(function() {
var tempId = $(this).attr("id");
$(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id")+"_"+(i))
var newID = $(this).attr("id");
}).end().appendTo("table");
});
=============Remove===============
$("table.normal-tble").on("click", "‪#‎remove‬", function (event) {
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
i -= 1
});
================code appending===================
<tbody>
<tr class="second">
<td style="text-align:left;"><form:select path="category" class="slt-tbl-small">
<form:option label="Select" value='0' />
<form:options itemLabel="categoryName" itemValue="category" items="${CategoryList}" />
</form:select>
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><form:select path="areaID" class="slt-tbl-small">
<form:option label="Select" value='0' />
</form:select>
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><form:select path="subAreaID" class="slt-tbl-small">
<form:option label="Select" value='0' />
</form:select>
</td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><form:input path="quantity" class="tfl-tbl-small"/></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><form:input path="availableBlocks" class="tfl-tbl-small"/></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><form:input path="utilization" class="tfl-tbl-small"/></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><form:input path="blkNumComment" class="tfl-small"/></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/edit.png"/>" width="14" height="13" alt="edit"></td>
<td style="text-align:left;"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/edit.png"/>" width="14" height="13" alt="edit" id = "remove"></td>
<td></td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
==================Fetch Data=================
$(this).change(function() {
var value = $(this).val();//this value is not coming for dynamically added select box.
});
});
===================================
```

Based on First select box change I have to populate values in other select boxes and text box.
1.How can I get the value of dynamically added select box?.
2.After clone the select boxes and text boxes even it has the same as previous not able to get the value and id.
3.Is it because of clone().

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: make sure you **delegate events** to account for elements that will be added after your initial page loading code runs. Or, make sure you bind events to new elements right after you insert them. Delegation is easier to manage. Read  through jQuery `on()` docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the onchange handler a named function:

```
function onChange() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //...
}
$(this).change(onChange);
```

And in your add function, add the same handler to the newly created element:

```
$(".normal-tble tbody tr:first").clone().find("select,input").each(function() {
    ///...
    $(this).change(onChange);
}).end().appendTo("table");
```

To your other question:
You should not assign both event handlers to your select+input+img. Do it separately, like this:

```
var $row = $(".normal-tble tbody tr:first").clone();
$row.find("select,input").change(onChange); 
$row.find("img").click(onClick);
$row.appendTo("table");
```

Comment: From the above code i have one image is there by clicking on it i have to populate some date.For that i have added click event while clone.like this  $(this).change(onChange).But it is conflicting my onchange.How can we avoid such conflict?.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem without seeing your actual code. You could edit your question, or post a new question.

Comment: dynamically added select box,textbox and image conflicting the events

Comment: One is a `change(onChange)` the other is a `click(onClick)`. They shouldn't conflict.

Comment: I need to create 3 types of elements dynamically,select box,textbox and img.i have to open a pop-up based on the value of select boxes and text by click of one of the img.So i added events for both while creation like $(".normal-tble tbody tr:first").clone().find("select,input,img").each(function() {
    $(this).click(onClick);
    $(this).change(onChange);
}).end().appendTo("table");

Comment: I see. I added an example to my answer. Hope it helps.